# Jquery ignore error when using Get function

Tags: jquery, ajax, openmap

System ignore my first $.get function and go to the second $.get function. I do test in Postman, it's working fine with `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=10.817841669295166&lon=106.64377723626976`. I try to catch this function, but no alert, no console log result. I don't know how.

Here's my code:

```js
$('.btncheckin').click(function() {
  console.log("button click");
  var btnid = $(this).attr('id');
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log("has navigator.geolocation");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      console.log("got current position, position");
      var address = "";
      $.get("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=10.817841669295166&lon=106.64377723626976", function(data1) {           
        console.log("has address info"); // new update
      })
      $.get("https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=" + position.coords.latitude + "&longitude=" + position.coords.longitude + "&localityLanguage=vi", function(data) {
        var time = 0;
        var dd = 0;
        var mm = 0;
        var yyyy = 0;
        console.log("got current latitude, longitude"); //new update
        $.ajax({
          url: '/Home/CheckIN?EmployeeCode=' + $("#msnv").val() + '&EmployeeIDNo=' + $("#cmnd").val() + '&Latitude=' + data.latitude + '&Longitude=' + data.longitude + '&CheckType=' + CheckType + '&Address=' + address,
          type: 'GET',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function(data) {
            if (data.IsSuccess)
              (
                $("#success").removeAttr("style"),
                $("#index").attr("style", "display: none !important"),
                $("#ggmap").attr("href", data.urlweb),
                $("#frame").attr("src", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=" + data.Latitude + "," + data.Longitude + "&key=[Mykey]"),
                time = +data.CheckDate.replace(/\D/g, ""),
                dd = String(new Date(time).getDate()).padStart(2, '0'),
                mm = String(new Date(time).getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'), //January is 0!
                yyyy = new Date(time).getFullYear(),
                $("#timecheckin").text(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " " + new Date(time).getHours() + ":" + new Date(time).getMinutes())

              )
          }
        })
      })
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<button class='btncheckin' id='btn'>click me</button>
```

Update: I got response from the server. I put 5 console log with one missing.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open the Network tab in Google Dev Tools and there you can check if your code is receiving response from the server. Afterwards, provide the information of success/error here. I will try to help

Comment: Also I made you a snippet. If the server allows CORS from stackoverflow, please add relevant HTML and jQuery version to make a [mcve]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot run it because there are no jQuery connected, you can try it by yourself. Even if you add jQuery in HTML section, there could be different result in your local server or where you are testing, so why information from your device required.

Comment: Added a button, but for me, `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` never returns

Comment: @dragomirik I received response from the server. I'm a new guy, I don't know how to upload image to this comment. So, I'll update in post.

Comment: @freedomn-m it's working for me. I got all 3 console logs, but lost in fourth log, and if I put a console log in second $.get, I'll get it.

Comment: FYI you can't put images in comments.

Comment: I updated my post, I received response from server.